# "Check, please" VS "Check out, please"

Tags: difference, phrase-request, idiomatic-language, idiom-request, sentence-request

When I finish a meal in a restaurant, which expression to pay for the food is more idiomatic?

- Check, please.
- Check out, please.

If they're both not idiomatic enough, please list the alternatives.

Also, if I want everyone to pay separately, what would be the idiomatic ways to ask for this?

Comment: "Checkout" normally applies to the till at a supermarket, not settling the bill in a restaurant. In the latter case I think most people would probably say something like ***Could we have the bill, please**?* - but it's highly subjective, and there is no "right" answer here.

Comment: People who have to keep repeating the same request over and over (a ticket inspector on a bus or train, say) often quite naturally dispense with the formalities, so they just say ***Tickets, please***. But even if you eat out every night, you won't exactly wear your mouth out by having to speak those extra four words *(**Could we have the**)* before ***Bill, please***). The two-word "clipped" version sounds just a bit peremptory / carelessly insulting to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the informative comments, if I want to do separate checks (everyone pays on their own), what would be the idiomatic way to ask for this?

Comment: "May we all pay separately, please?"

Comment: Where I come from (UK) we say 'can I have the _bill_ please?'

Comment: @FumbleFingers - on my bus rides to school around 1963, a regular elderly conductor used to say what I heard as 'Ithankyew'. My mother rolled her eyes and said it was a catch-phrase originated by [Arthur Askey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Askey) a long time before.

Comment: Agree with @FumbleFingers - if you watch movies and TV shows, you might think that "check, please" is common, but IRL it's not polite.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, "May we all pay separately, please?" is said to the cashier, right? If so, what should I say to the payers to ask for separate payments?

Comment: "Shall we all pay separately?", or "Shall we ask if they will split the bill between us?" (or _check_ in American English.)

Comment: You also use checkout in hotels when leaving to ask for your final bill but not in a restaurant.

Comment: @mdewey You meant "check out", right? Since ["checkout" is a noun](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/checkout).

Comment: Yes, sorry, the process is checkout but you would say "Check out, please"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Check out" is actually a separate idiom that is not applicable in this context; it refers to the procedure of a formal action of leaving some place where you had been booked in, like a hotel. In "check out", the word "check" is actually a verb -- not a noun. "Check, please" sounds perfectly fine, I cannot possibly see how it could be interpreted as "blunt" or "impolite". [Seeing it as insulting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/300718/check-please-vs-check-out-please/300746#comment560811_300718) surprises me as being grotesquely over-sensitized, and gives me the impression that the dictionary definition word "insult" has been, unbeknownst to be, replaced overnight with something completely different from the original meaning. Being curt with one's words does not equal being impolite, especially since this phrase uses the word "please". Being polite also means respecting the other person's time and not wasting it by making them participate in unnecessary exchange of verbose platitudes and pleasantries. And also, you might want to use an appropriate regionalism; "check" for American and Canadian English, "bill" for British and Australian English.

Answer (score 1):

The most common phrasing is “check, please.” I think this sounds a little blunt so I often say “Could I get the check please?” which I think is a little more polite.

If you want to pay separately, just ask the server for “separate checks” at the beginning of the meal.